# meaning of " Development of an Anomaly Detection Model for a Bank’s Transitory Account System"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can you please explain what this means in simpler terms?

> Development of an
>   Anomaly Detection Model
>   for a Bank’s Transitory
>   Account System

Comment: The development of a model for detecting anomalies in the system banks use to manage their transitory accounts. You can look up "transitory accounts" on Google, as it is a term of trade used in the banking sector.

Answer (score 1):

A bank processes many transactions each day.  When those transactions are processed, the funds might be stored in what is called a *transitory* or *temporary* account that only exists for the amount of time necessary to complete the transaction.

Sometimes there are *discrepancies* in those transitory accounts -- the funds are not completely transferred, or they are not closed properly, or various other *anomalies*.

The title proposes the *development* of a system to *detect* those anomalies.